# Convert Each Array within a 2D Array into String

Tags: python, arrays, search, 2d

Im trying to convert each element within a 2D array into a string. So for example i would like to convert something like this [ ['a' , 'b' , 'c'] , ['x' , 'y' , 'z'] ] into something like this ['abc' , 'xyz']. Im pretty sure this is possible but i cant seem to understand how. Please can something let me know. Thanks

I have already tried to join the array and convert it to string and stuff but i cant seem to get it. I think i may not have enough knowledge about syntax which is why i am stuck.

```
def combs(a):
    if len(a) == 0:
        return [[]]
    cs = []
    for x in combs(a[1:]):
        cs = cs + [x, x+[a[0]]]
    return cs

a = ["J","a","m","e","s"]
c = combs(a[::-1])

arr = []

for element in c:
    arr.append(element)
print(arr)

#I would like to do this to the 'arr' array please.
#Everything else works how I would like it to.
```

I would just like to have all of the possible combinations in a 1d array as string elements.

Comment: `main_list =  [ ['a' , 'b' , 'c'] , ['x' , 'y' , 'z'] ]; [''.join(x) for x in main_list]` ?

Comment: i will try and let u know

Comment: yes it worked !!! Thank you so much

Comment: Ive been scratching my head for ages lol. Thanks again

Comment: In Python those are [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) not arrays.  Your *2d array* is a list of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr = [ ['a' , 'b' , 'c'] , ['x' , 'y' , 'z'] ]

for index, i in enumerate(arr):
    arr[index] = ''.join(i)

print(arr)
```

Shortened version:

```
arr = [''.join(i) for i in arr]
print(arr)
```